# Tell a field to be translatable

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, i18n-l10n

I have a module with a plugin block. In the blockForm I create all the fields that I need for this block. In the CMS I realized that only the title of my block is translatable. I need some of my custom fields to be translatable. I just can't find how to do that.

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

    [...]

    $form['exit_link']['full_schedule_link'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Full Schedule Link'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter the schedule node, ex: (/node/20)'),
      '#default_value' => isset($this->configuration['full_schedule_link'])?    $this->configuration['full_schedule_link']:'',
      '#maxlength' => 256,
      '#size' => 64,
      '#weight' => '1',
      '#translatable' => true // <-- NOT WORKING
    );

    [...]

}
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define that through the config schema, not the form.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/1905070, use type: label (weird know but that's how it is called) not string and type: text for textareas.

If you have no config schema yet, look at other modules providing blocks with configuration, like aggregator.module to see how to define that.

Comment: The aggregator module was a great help for this. But when I want to translate a body that is wysiwyg it turns up to be a textarea in the translation. I used `type: text`. Is there a way to get the wysiwyg in the translation form or it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Following the Aggregator module as an example, I implemented the following code to alter the translation form and add the WYSIWYG text format.

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (($form_id == 'config_translation_edit_form' || $form_id == 'config_translation_add_form') && isset($form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation'])) {
    if (is_array($form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value'])) {
      $default_value = isset($form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value']['value']) ?
        $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value']['value'] : '';
      $default_format = isset($form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value']['format']) ?
        $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value']['format'] : 'rich_text';
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value'] = $default_value;
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#format'] = $default_format;
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#type'] = 'text_format';
    }
    else {
      $default_value = isset($form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value']) ?
        $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value'] : '';
      $default_format = 'rich_text';
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#default_value'] = $default_value;
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#format'] = $default_format;
      $form['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['translation']['#type'] = 'text_format';
    }
  }
// here reverse the order of the submit handlers, so that the we can manage the values before the default submit
  $form['#submit'][0] = 'mymodule_form_submit';
  $form['#submit'][1] = '::submitForm';
}

function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $field_name= $form_state->getValue('translation')['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['field_name']['value'];
  // this is the label of the block
  $label = $form_state->getValue('translation')['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings']['label'];
  $translation['config_names']['block.block.block_id']['settings'] = [
    'label' => $label,
    'field_name' => $field_name,
  ];

    $form_state->setValue('translation', $translation);
}
```

After altering the form, it won't submit right, and the values wouldn't display for the second language. I had to add a submit handler in order to send the right arrays to the default submit. 
Not sure if this is the best way, but it is working right.

I thought that this may be  helpful for those users who run into this issue.